# ionic : play audio file at regular interval

Tags: ionic-framework, background, media, schedule

I need to develop an ionic app(for ios and android both) which can play audio at regular interval. e.g. every 2 hours in night only.
This should play even if app is in background.
Any other idea is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a native HTML5 player to reproduce your audio.
Take a look at this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio